# Generate a histogram with exponentially increasing bin width by ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have not found a way to display an histogram with increasing binwidth in ggplot. Is there a way?

Comment: If you use `scale_x_log10()` you will get the same effect

Answer (score 2):

I found it myself:

```
breeaks <- c(0,1,2*2^(0:10))
mygg <- ggplot(Grains, aes(Shape_Area)) + theme_bw() + xlab("Size") + geom_histogram(breaks = breeaks, col =3)
mygg
```

gives:

[image: exponential increasing bin width]

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer documented it seems, but you can still pass manual bin breaks to `stat_bin` (and `geom_histogram`). For example:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
    stat_bin(breaks = c(0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1, 2, 5))
```

[image]

Or:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat)) +
    geom_histogram(breaks = (seq(0, 2, 0.1)) ^ 2, col = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not quite right: The bins are not increasing exponentially. Thank you for giving me the hint in the right direction, though.

Comment: I figured the exact required bin sizes were pretty trivial from this point.